# Using laravel storage

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I'm trying to use **laravel's** `Storage` facade to allow users to upload and download files.

I'm using the `local` driver. inside I have the following directory **structure:**

```
storage/
       app/
          uploads/
                 files/
```

I created a symbolic ink using the following **command:**

```
ln -s storage/app/uploads/files public/uploads/files
```

So far I am able to store files into the `/files directory`. The problem comes when I try to download.

```
$exists = Storage::disk('local')->exists('uploads/files/' . $upload->file_name);
    $file_path = Storage::url('uploads/files/' . $upload->file_name);

    if ($exists) {

        $header = [
            'Content-Length' => $upload->size,
            'Content-Type' => $upload->mime
        ];

        return response()->download($file_path, $upload->title . '.' . $upload->type, $header);
}
```

For some reason the `value of exists is false??`

Edit 1:
I've corrected the mistake of adding a forward slash but I'm not able to download the file. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

i think you

```
$exists = Storage::disk('local')->exists('uploads/files' . $upload->file_name);
```

you missed '/'

```
$exists = Storage::disk('local')->exists('uploads/files/' . $upload->file_name);
```

this will mai help you

Comment: Thank you the exists() function returns 1 now but I'm still not able to download the file.

Comment: @user3552551 you should include error messages, stating "i'm not able" doesn't help anyone determine **how** it fails.